# SQL query for fetching users and common friends

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know similiar questions have been asked and answered before, I have reviewed them but still can't quite wrap my head around how to do this in my case.

I would like to create a query (I use postgreSQL) that would return users from my database filtered by name, sorted by the number of friends in common with a given user (the user sending the request).

The data structure is as follows:

- I have a `users` table, that has a column called `search_full_name` which stores name + surname in the format of "ADAM SMITH". This is what I filter with.
- I have a `user_friends` table that stores information about who is friends with whom. So I have two columns in there: `user_id` and `friend_id` . The data is symmetric, i.e. for every (1,3) there is a (3,1) entry.

So far in the friend search I was just using a query like

```
select * from users where users.search_full_name like '%query%'
```

But now, I would like to additionally order the result by the amount of friends in common with the user asking, so my query would have two inputs: `query` and `userId`.

Turns out I am not as good with sql as I thought, and I would really appreciate your help, it would be  great to see some explanations too.

I imagine the desired output as:

```
+---------+------------------+----------------------+--+
| user_id | search_full_name | common_friends_count |  |
+---------+------------------+----------------------+--+
|      45 | Adam Smith       |                   14 |  |
|     123 | Adam Cole        |                   11 |  |
|      12 | Adamic Kapi      |                    0 |  |
+---------+------------------+----------------------+--+
```

for a query like 'Adam'

I have been trying this for a whole day now and I feel my brain has exploded.
Please help, thanks

Comment: How do you know who the user asking the question is?  Sample data and desired results would also make your question easier to. understand.

Comment: I will take that from the  request context in my app and just pass it on to the query as a parameter

Comment: @GordonLinoff , I edited my post and included a desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is a self-join.  The following gets a match on users who share friends with the specified user:

```
select uf2.user_id, count(*) as num_friends
from user_friends uf join
     user_friends uf2
     on uf2.friend_id = uf.friend_id and
        uf2.user_id <> uf2.user_id
where uf2.user_id = ?
group by uf2.user_id
order by count(*) desc;  -- the user you care about
```

Comment: I need to query the users table, because I want to search for users by a query phrase, just order by the ammount of common friends with the current user. So I would need to have a select from users u (...) where u.search_full_name like '%query%' . And where (...) is, is where the magic is necessary to somehow join the user_friends table to be able to order by the count. See the desired output in the original post

Comment: btw. I saw your post in a similiar question, with this self-join approach, but I can't really get it to work in my example. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a few hours I came up with a query that works :) Here it is for future reference:

```
select u.id, u.search_full_name, count(uf.friend_id) as common_friend_count
from users u left join user_friends uf on (u.id = uf.user_id and uf.friend_id in (select friend_id from user_friends where user_id = ?))
where u.search_full_name like ?
group by u.search_full_name, u.id
order by common_friend_count desc;
```